# MS Access: How can I count the number of instances of the same record within the same query?

Tags: ms-access, count, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, grouping

I have the query below (note - grouping on job and item):

```
Query A

job        item         
A1         1001
B1         1002
C1         1001
```

I want it to look like this (still grouped on job and item):

```
Query A

job        item    count_item      
A1         1001      2
B1         1002      1
C1         1001      2
```

The idea is that I want the result set to count how many times a record in the item field appears and display in the same query *without using a subquery* and without *joining on another custom query* that would do the count separately. Is this possible?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by "without using another query". Without using a subquery? Without using another saved query? ...?

Comment: @HansUp No, I don't.

Comment: @whatwhatwhat: That makes little sense. Calling `DCount()` for each result row is much less efficient than a subquery with `GROUP BY Item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.

You need to either group only by `item` (not by `job`), or join a subquery that has `GROUP BY item` and counts the rows.

Comment: Are there no functions that count something in a *result set*?